# top tf-idf keywords per class

Tags: python, pandas, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to find out what words have the strongest td-idf score per class.
Let's say I have the following data frame, and class is the 'artist' column:

| lyrics | artist |
| --- | --- |
| Sample lyrics 1 | Wu-Tang Clan |
| Sample lyrics 2 | N.W.A. |
| Sample lyrics 3 | N.W.A. |
| Sample lyrics 4 | A Tribe Called Quest |

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp

from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer, CountVectorizer

artist_list = df['artist'].values
unique_values = np.unique(artist_list)
artists = unique_values.tolist()

# Create documents per label
docs = df
docs_per_class = docs.groupby(['artist'], as_index=False).agg({'lyrics': ' '.join})

# Create bag of words
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer().fit(docs_per_class.lyrics)
count = count_vectorizer.transform(docs_per_class.lyrics)
words = count_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# Extract top 10 words per class
ctfidf = CTFIDFVectorizer().fit_transform(count, n_samples=len(docs)).toarray()
words_per_class = {artists[label]: [words[index] for index in ctfidf[label].argsort()[-10:]] 
                   for label in docs_per_class.artist}
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What's incorrect here?

The solution I am trying to implement is described here: https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-a-class-based-tf-idf-with-scikit-learn-caea7b15b858

Answer (score 0):

artist_to_index = {artist: i for i, artist in enumerate(artists)}
words_per_class = {artists[artist_to_index[label]]: [words[index] for index in ctfidf[artist_to_index[label]].argsort()[-10:]]
for label in docs_per_class.artist}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).